# How to reset iOS-Charts animation in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using a line chart from iOS-Charts in a custom tableview cell that expands on touch. I'm not loading the charts in cellForRow: since this loads all the charts in all the cells and kills scrolling performance, so I have it loading in didSelectRow:. The problem is that for some reason, the chart doesn't load the first time a user touches a cell and I have no idea why. Also, it seems like the chart animation starts  when an expanded cell (that is currently showing a chart) is collapsed.

Here is my didSelectRow: and below is the charting func in my custom cell. I've been wrestling with this, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      let cell:CandDetailTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CandDetailTableViewCell

      // CALLS METHOD TO BUILD CHART WITH DATA I SAVED IN THESE ARRAYS
      cell.setChart(dataForMonths, values: dataForRatings)

      let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath

      if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {

         // if user taps cell that was already selected so it collapses
         selectedIndexPath = nil

      } else {

         // when user selects new cell
         selectedIndexPath = indexPath
      }

      var indexPaths:Array <NSIndexPath> = []

      if let previous = previousIndexPath {

         indexPaths += [previous]
      }

      if let current = selectedIndexPath {

         indexPaths += [current]
      }

      if indexPaths.count > 0 {

         tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
      }

      tableView.scrollRectToVisible(tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath), animated: true)
   }
```

Here is chart func in the tableview cell:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

          var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

          for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

             let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)

             dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
          }

          let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Rating")
          let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)

          analyticsView.data = lineChartData
          analyticsView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
          analyticsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

          analyticsView.userInteractionEnabled = false
          analyticsView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
          analyticsView.drawBordersEnabled = false
          analyticsView.leftAxis.enabled = false
          analyticsView.rightAxis.enabled = false
          analyticsView.xAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.0
          analyticsView.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.clearColor()

          analyticsView.legend.enabled = false

          // Removes the description text off the chart
          analyticsView.descriptionText = ""

          analyticsView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, put `analyticsView.data = lineChartData` after you setup your chat view. It needs to read some properties to do some math;

second, when and where you add the chart view into the cell's content view?

Also, it seems a little strange when you call `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)` in didSelectRow, I assume you should add the chart view into cell's content view here, not reload data? Because it will trigger another `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and override what you have done?

basically when you do `addSubView`, it will start drawing the chart. You can add a break point at `addSubView` and `drawRect` of the line chart view, and see if it can break when you hit the cell.

You can also manually trigger a redraw by `chartView.setneedsDisplay`

Update:

If you want to reset animation, call the animate API again and maybe another setNeedsDisplay

Comment: I changed `analyticsView.data = lineChartData` to be at the end after it sets up the chart view; it still runs the same. I am adding the chart view when I call `cell.setChart(dataForMonths, values: dataForRatings)` in didSelectRow: and displaying in a UIView in my cell.

Comment: then you should start debugging when the drawRect is called